# How to bridge a wifi connection between two computers by wifi 

Tags: linux, networkmanager, hotspot, wireless-bridge

Pc 1 : netbook with an usb wifi antenna spotted on a free wifi hotspot

Pc 2 : same model netbook that can't access internet

What I need : Share the wifi connection by the 2 internal WLAN on ubuntu by network-manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to configure an ad-hoc wirless network with the two internal wifi cards and route the traffic out through the other wireless card.

You can try this method as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing#Wireless%20Ad-Hoc%20connection%20sharing%20scenario).

1. At the terminal install execute `sudo apt-get install dnsmasq-base` and then `sudo apt-get remove dnsmasq`
2. Restart the NetworkManager by executing `sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart`
3. Left-click on the NetworkManager icon and click "Create New Wireless Network"
4. Name it "UbuntuAdhoc" and set the encryption to "WEP40"
5. Connect PC2 using Ad-Hoc to the PC1

Read [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Adhoc) and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing) for more information on the subject.